# Find latest entries in array over all documents

Tags: mongodb

I have multiple documents which contain an array with objects. How can I find the latest entries in the array but over all documents. As an example:

```
{
  doctitle: “some title”,
  conditions: [
    {
      createdAt: ISODate("2014-12-21T13:59:26Z"),
      title: “some title 1”
    }, 
    {
      createdAt: ISODate("2014-12-22T13:59:26Z"),
      title: “some title 2”
    }
  ]
},
{
  doctitle: “other title”,
  conditions: [
    {
      createdAt: ISODate("2014-12-20T13:59:26Z"),
      title: “some title 3”
    }, 
    {
      createdAt: ISODate("2014-12-23T13:59:26Z"),
      title: “some title 4”
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to find the latest 3 conditions. It should output each document just with the docTitle and the one condition found.

```
{
  docTitle: "other title" ,
  condition: [ 
      {
      createdAt: ISODate("2014-12-23T13:59:26Z"),
      title: “some title 4”
     }
  ]
},
{
  docTitle: "some title" ,
  condition: [ 
      {
      createdAt: ISODate("2014-12-22T13:59:26Z"),
      title: “some title 2”
     }
  ]
},
{
  docTitle: "some title" ,
  condition: [ 
      {
      createdAt: ISODate("2014-12-21T13:59:26Z"),
      title: “some title 1”
     }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the actual achema, provide the actual data type for the field `createdAt`, it doesn't look like a valid MongoDB date.

Comment: createdAt should be a valid MongoDB date. It was more as an example. I don't have the schema in place yet.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, it would be really helpful if you could clarify that by actually updating the values as well as your expected output from that sample data.

Comment: I changed my previous question. Is that clear?

Comment: Much better now, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following aggregation pipeline which does an initial **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** operator to "denormalise" the documents by the conditions array field so that each output document replaces the array with an element value. For each input document, outputs n documents where n is the number of array elements and can be zero for an empty array.

The next pipeline step uses the **[`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort)** operator to re-order the documents by the embedded `createdAt` field which is necessary for the next couple of pipeline steps, i.e. the **[`$limit`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/#pipe._S_limit)** and **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** operators.

Since you require only the top three documents ordered by the `createdAt` field descending, **[`$limit`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/#pipe._S_limit)** does just that for you by passing the first 3 documents unmodified to the pipeline where the specified limit is 3.

The preceding **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline stage is where you derive the "doctitle" field through the use of the **[`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first)** and modified conditions array through **[`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push)** accumulator operators when you group the documents by the `createdAt` field as the key.

The last pipeline step **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** removes the `_id` field from the previous pipeline stream thus the final pipeline would look like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$conditions" },
    { "$sort": { "conditions.createdAt": -1 }  },
    { "$limit": 3 },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$conditions.createdAt",
            "doctitle" : { "$first": "$doctitle" },
            "conditions": { "$push": "$conditions" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0, "doctitle": 1, "conditions": 1
        }
    }
])
```

**Sample Output:**

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "doctitle" : "some title",
            "conditions" : [ 
                {
                    "createdAt" : ISODate("2014-12-21T13:59:26.000Z"),
                    "title" : "some title 1"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "doctitle" : "some title",
            "conditions" : [ 
                {
                    "createdAt" : ISODate("2014-12-22T13:59:26.000Z"),
                    "title" : "some title 2"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "doctitle" : "other title",
            "conditions" : [ 
                {
                    "createdAt" : ISODate("2014-12-23T13:59:26.000Z"),
                    "title" : "some title 4"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Pretty awesome! Thanks a lot

Comment: @Chris No worries, happy to help.